# regex help to return page titles which do and dont include /n tags etc

Tags: php, regex

i have been looking for ages for a regular expression which will return all page titles. unfortuantley some have newline tags in them and other wiered stuff which is preventing me from finding a result.

here are some of the regex's i have tried

```
"/\<title.*\>(.+)\<\/title\>/"


"#\<title.*\>(.+)\<\/title\>#s"
```

but none of them return titles with /n tags
can anyone help me out please?

many thanks
Luke

## edit

here is the full code

```
$data = file_get_contents("http://www.awin1.com/pclick.php?p=116824093&a=79524&m=2694&platform=cs");
$subject = $data;
$pattern = '#<title.*>(.+)</title>#s';
preg_match($pattern,$subject,$matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

obviously the link changes
thanks

Comment: /n tags? Do you mean line breaks (`\n`)?

Comment: yes mate thats what i ment :)

Answer (score 1):

As long as you put 'dot matches newline' on, this will work just fine:

```
<title>.*?</title>
```

For 'dot matches newline' you'll have to postfix the regex with `/s` in PHP.

```
preg_match("/<title>(.*?)</title>/s", someTextToSearch)
```

Comment: hi mate, thanks for your quick reply unfortunatly it doesnt seem to work for the way im using it??? maybe im using it wrong?                         [code]$data = file_get_contents($link);                                                
                        $subject = $data;
                        $pattern = "<title>.*?</title>";
                        preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches);
                        print_r($matches);[/code]

Comment: Try encapsulating the `.*?` by `(` and `)` to make it a group, like in my second sample./

Comment: thats returning a null? when used like so [code]preg_match("/<title>(.*?)</title>/s", $data, $matches);
var_dump($matches);[/code]

Comment: You're using `/` as the regex delimiter, so you need to escape the literal `/` in the regex: `'/<title>(.*?)<\/title>/s'`.  You also don't allow for attributes within the `<title>` tag, but that's down to the OP, who never mentioned them.  But +1 for using a reluctant `.*?`; all the other solutions have to scarf up the whole page, then backtrack all the way back to the closing `</title>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, have you considered using PHP's DOM functions instead of regex? Using regex can be quite fraught when trying to parse html.

If you still want to use regex...

1) The dot operator (that you're using already) matches "any character except line feeds". However there is an option that you can enable to switch it to be "any character including line feeds".

2) Or you could continue using dot, plus `\n` and `\r`, which are the two line feed characters you're likely to encounter - so `(.|\n|\r)` where you currenty have just the dot.

3) Another alternative would be to use str_replace() to get rid of all the line feed characters before doing the regex. (this won't affect your html output in the browser).

Comment: hi mate, have tried adding (.|\n|\r) but still no luck. how would one str_replace? would that need to be done on the whole page code returned? cheers

Comment: I believe the DOM parsing function would be a resource hog just to parse out the title.

Answer (score 0):

For me it works just fine (with \n )

```
$sgml = <<<HTML
<title>fooo bar ? \n
baz! </title>
HTML;

preg_match('#\<title.*\>(.+)\<\/title\>#s',$sgml,$matches);

var_dump($matches); // dumps array(2) { [0]=>  string(33) "" [1]=>  string(18) "fooo bar ? baz! " }
```

Or did i understood you wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Erm this works? Am I missing something?

```
$data = file_get_contents("http://www.awin1.com/pclick.php?p=116824093&a=79524&m=2694&platform=cs"); 
$subject = $data; 
preg_match('!<title?[^>]+>(.+)</title>!is', $subject, $matches); 
var_dump(trim($matches[1]));
```

Comment: hi mate that works for the given url but not for this url? [code]http://www.awin1.com/pclick.php?p=115443605&a=79524&m=1418&platform=cs[/code]? think this is because the title tags on this page are not as straight forward as they are something like this [code]<title id="_header__header__title">[/code] and the above expression doesnt like this. any ideas. thanks mate

Comment: I think it's a problem with the play.com url. If you use the html source with the above code it will work fine, however if you use it with the file_get_contents play.com url it won't work. Odd.

Comment: hm that is strange. this regex works for it but not sure how to add it to the above one? [code]/\<title.*\>(.+)\<\/title\>/
[/code] cheers

Comment: try - echo file_get_contents('http://www.awin1.com/pclick.php?p=115443605&a=79524&m=1418&platform=cs'); // it returns some weird characters at the start of the string. I think this is the problem. not the regexs

Comment: what do you mean "add it to the above one"?

Comment: is it possible to combine the two into one expression?

Comment: yes - '!<title?[^>]+>(.+)</title>!is' This will match titles with and without attributes.

Comment: have echo'd out file_get_contents('http://www.awin1.com/pclick.php?p=115443605&a=79524&m=1418&platform=cs'); and it just returns the play.com page, cant see any wierd chars? cheers

Comment: i have tried using the new expression and it works sometimes??? not sure why it doesnt work all the time, as im using the same url...

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get any of the solutions on this page to work 100%-- some title tags have newline characters, some have tabs, and some are cased irregularly.  In all these cases the regex will fail.

Thusfar the best all-inclusive expression I have found (& tested) is this:

```
$res = preg_match('/<title>(.*?)<\/title>/is', $fp, $title_matches);
```